# How comma separated range mechanism works in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array([[1,3,5],[2,4,6]])

print(z[0:, :2])
```

**Answer:**

```
[[1, 3] [2, 4]]
```

I am a python beginner, I was solving an interactive exercise when the above mentioned question appeared.

I am not able to understand, how z[0:, :2] works in this case? If possible, please help me understand this scenario.

Comment: The first part of the index notation indicates the rows (first axis), and the second one indicates the columns or second axis. In this case you are choosing from the first to 3rd column, as `:2` is contain `0, 1` columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read about Numpy slicing and indexing here:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

In this case, `0:` means "all the rows, starting from (and including) row 0 and going until the end" (you could also just use the equivalent `:`, which means "all the rows, starting from the beginning and going until the end").

`:2` means "all the columns, starting from the beginning and going until (but not including) column 2".

Together, `z[0:, :2]` means "the part of `z` that includes all the rows and the first two columns". The first dimension listed is rows, and the second is columns. If your array was 3D, you could include yet another dimension with another comma, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

First you ask to get all rows (`0:` is the same as `:`):

```
[[1,3,5],
 [2,4,6]]
```

Then you ask for columns 0 and 1 (`:2` is the same as `0:2` which means from 0 until 2 exclusive):

```
[[1,3],
 [2,4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`z[0:, :2]` selects all elements in all (ie., both) rows (`0:` selects the range of row indices starting with 0) and in the first two columns (`:2` selects the column indices 0 and 1.)

```
 column  0 1 2
--------------
row 0 |  1 3 5
row 1 |  2 4 6
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of numpy arrays, and, in this example, applies to 2D arrays.

If `z = np.array([l0, l1, l2, l3])` where l0, l1, l2, l3 are lists,

then `z[1:3,2:5] = [l1[2:5], l2[2:5]]`

So the first slice argument applies to the outer list, while the second argument applies to the inner lists. This generalizes to 3D numpy arrays, etc.

Here's the doc:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html